# accessing map with C++98 standard

Tags: c++, c++11, c++98

I have the following C++11 compatible code and I need to compile it with C++98 which doesn't have support for '.at'. How to rewrite it to be compatible with C++98 ?

```
String suffix("sss");
headers_t& meta = ...;
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> headerpair_t;
typedef std::map<std::string, headerpair_t> addheader_t;

addheader_t addheader;

for(headerpair_t::const_iterator piter = addheader.at(suffix).begin(); piter !=  addheader.at(suffix).end(); ++piter){
    // Adding header
    meta[(*piter).first] = (*piter).second;
}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/
there's [] operator

Comment: @aryjczyk `operator[]` is similar but behaves differently when the element is not found. `operator[]` inserts a new element in this case, whereas `at` throws an `out_of_range` exception. That also implies that `operator[]` is not `const` and can therefore not be used for `const map`s, whereas `at` can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create an `at()` function which mimicks what C++11 `std::map<...>::at()` does:

```
template <typename K, typename V, typename C, typename A>
V const& at(std::map<K, V, C, A> const& m, K const& k) {
    typename std::map<K, V, C, A>::const_iterator it(m.find(k));
    if (it == m.end()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("key not found in map");
    }
    return it->second;
}
```

Note that calling `at()` in each iteration of a loop is a Bad Idea! Searching a `std::map<...>` is *efficient* in the theoretical sense but that doesn't mean that it is fast in practice! You are **much** better off to search the relevant node just one and then keep using it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: fixed the issues (the `typename` and `.` vs. `->` were just typos). I wasn't aware that there would be an implicit conversion due to the `throw` expression, though (need to look closer at that). Thanks!

Comment: Neither was I. My complaint was invalid (at least my reason for it was). I didn't realize that a throw statement was an expression. Tested it and found I was wrong.

Comment: Well, [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) warns about the conditional operator: `warning: returning reference to local temporary object` In principle you can throw from one branch of a conditional operator but it seems you can't get references through...

Comment: Yeah, GCC gives a similar warning.  I thought it would give a compiler error, and I didn't really understand the warning.

Comment: I'm getting:curl.cpp: In function `const V& at(const std::map<K, V, std::less<_Key>, 
   std::allocator<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> > >&, const K&) [with K = 
   std::string, V = headerpair_t]':
curl.cpp:3336:   instantiated from here
curl.cpp:3312: error: `range_error' undeclared in namespace `std'
curl.cpp:3312: error: 'struct std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const 
   std::string, headerpair_t>, const std::pair<const std::string, 
   headerpair_t>&, const std::pair<const std::string, headerpair_t>*>' has no 
   member named 'second'

Comment: @ShanMuh: yes, there were a few typos in the code which are fixed in the current version! You'd also need to include `<stdexcept>` from the looks of it.

Comment: I'm getting this now: curl.cpp:3315: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const headerpair_t&' from expression of type 'int'

Comment: Your template is missing the last two template parameters of `std::map`, as is it will only work with maps using the default comparator and allocator.

Comment: @ShanMuh: The version of `at()` I posted above does work. The problem you are encountering now seems to be unrelated. [Here](http://ideone.com/aN8qQr) is a live example of the code (I have removed some of your code because it was incomplete).

Comment: @Casey: I have added the missing two template parameters. The code in the question didn't use them but you are right: there is no reason to create a partial solution.

Comment: Yep this works ! The problem was that I'm trying to compile it for a 2005 Debian which doesn't have the stdexcept header (and I don't want to install it). So I ended up modifying your code a little bit for the error handling part. Thanks !

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20848132/1120273) revealed (in a comment) that there is a defect about the conditional operator returning a prvalue if one branch throws an exception which seems to get fixed by retaining the type of the expression and observing its kind.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `at()` in a `for` loop condition like that. The element does not change between iteration and there is a overhead in retrieving it at every turn. So you should just retrieve it using [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) and then loop on the iterators:

```
addheader_t::const_iterator header_iter = addheader.find(suffix); // Retrieve the element

if (header_iter != addheader.end()) // Check that it does exist
{
  // Retrieve the sub-map in the pair
  const headerpair_t& header_pair_map = it->second;

  // Loop on the elements
  for (headerpair_t::const_iterator it = header_pair_map.begin(); header_pair_map.end(); ++it)
  {
    // Use insert to avoid a useless element construction
    // Use also `std::make_pair`, but can we directly insert the pair from headerpair ?
    meta.insert(std::make_pair(it->first, it->second));
  }
}
```