# Can an exception be thrown from the ternary operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Sometimes it is convenient or even necessary to have a function which just one statement (it is necessary when returning a `constexpr`). If a condition needs to be checked and only one statement is allowed, the conditional operator is the only option. In case of an error it would be nice to throw an exception from the conditional operator, e.g.:

```
template <typename It>
typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference
access(It it, It end) {
    return it == end? throw std::runtime_error("no element"): *it;
}
```

The above function doesn't compile, however, when used for example as ([live example](http://ideone.com/pXAWrx)):

```
std::vector<int> v;
access(v.begin(), v.end());
```

The compiler complains about trying to bind a non-`const` reference to a temporary. The compiler doesn't complain about the `throw`-expression per se, though. So the question: Can exceptions be thrown from the conditional operator and, if so, what's going wrong with the above code?

Comment: It compiles with a modification of the return type: http://ideone.com/pjOkh8.

Comment: @stefan: If you make the function return by value then it will *copy*, it is no longer the same function!

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas true, but it eliminates the compile error and reveals that at least this compiler doesn't choke on the ternary operator with exceptions.

Comment: It's arguably a defect, see [CWG 1560](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1560) and [CWG 1550](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1550)

Comment: Note that the with C++14, the ternary operator loses its importance in `constexpr` (fully supported as of Clang 3.4, e.g. on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com). Throwing exceptions inside `constexpr` combined with the comma operator seems to be [the idiomatic way to handle errors](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/compile-time-computations/).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The conditional operator is described in 5.16 [expr.cond]. Its paragraph 2 includes the following text:

> The second or the third operand (but not both) is a *throw-expression* (15.1); the result is of the type of the other and is a prvalue.

That says that it is allowed to throw an exception from the conditional operator. However, even if the other branch is an lvalue, it is turned into an rvalue! Thus, it isn't possible to bind an lvalue to the result of a conditional expression. Aside from rewriting the condition using the comma operator, the code could be rewritten to only obtain the lvalue from the result of the conditional operator:

```
template <typename It>
typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference
access(It it, It end) {
    return *(it == end? throw std::runtime_error("no element"): it);
}
```

The somewhat tricky business is that returning a `const` reference from the function would compile but actually return a reference to a temporary!

Comment: You should accept this answer, as it answers the question and also provides insight into possible pitfalls

Answer (score 13):

The wording in the standard is around 5.16/2:

> If either the second or the third operand has type void, then the lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are performed on the second and third operands, and one of the following shall hold:
>
> — The second or the third operand (but not both) is a throw-expression (15.1); the result is of the type of the other and is a prvalue.

Which explains the behavior you are getting. It is legal to throw, but the type of the expression is a *pure-rvalue* (even if the expression is an *lvalue*) and you cannot thus bind a non-const *lvalue-reference*

Answer (score 12):

It can be done like this:

```
return it == end? (throw std::runtime_error("no element"),*it): *it;
```

Comment: That's one way of avoiding the problem, but IMO `*(it == end ? throw ... : it)` looks neater.

Comment: Heh, and that's exactly what Dietmar Kühl was putting in his own answer as I posted this comment. :)

Comment: @hvd: although moving the dereference to the outsise looks neater it copies the iterator, at least, conceptually. Using the comma operator should avoid the need to copy the iterator.

Comment: @DietmarKühl You're right. However, an iterator that's expensive to copy is not something I worry about, and given the fact that you take iterator parameters by value, it's not really something you seem to worry about either. So in this case, readability has a higher priority for me, but you and others can legitimately come to different conclusions.

Comment: @hvd I think the real advantage of your/Dietmar's solution is that you don't have to repeat the expression. The advantage of my solution is that it is possible even for more complicated expressions (and the first expression after the comma operator could be shortened). Maybe one should just decide which style is more appropriate on a case-by-case base.