# What happens when an exception is thrown while computing a constexpr?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr

When computing constant expressions to initialize a `constexpr` it is possible to throw exceptions. For example here is an example where the computation of a constant expression is guarded against overflow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

constexpr int g(int n, int n0, int n1) {
    return n == 0? n1: g(n - 1, n1, n0 + n1);
}

constexpr int f(int n) {
    return n < 42? g(n, 0, 1): throw std::out_of_range("too big");
}

int main()
{
    try {
        constexpr int f41 = f(41); // OK: constexpr
        int           f43 = f(43); // OK: throws an exception
        constexpr int f42 = f(42); // not OK but what happens?
    }
    catch (std::exception const& ex) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: " << ex.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

The first call to `f()` just shows that a `constexpr` can be computed. The second call to `f()` isn't used to initialize a `constexpr` and throws a run-time exception. The third call to `f()` is used to initialize a `constexpr` but that point won't ever reached because an exception is thrown. However, what should happen in this case? I would expect the handler in the `catch`-clause is executed but both [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) produce a compile-time error.

Comment: Haven't you asked something similar recently? Doesn't the evaluation of the throw-expression simply make the evaluated constexpr function a *not-a-constant-expression*?

Comment: I think [expr.const]/2 applies: A conditional expression is *not* a core constant expression if it contains "an invocation of a `constexpr` function with arguments that, when substituted by function invocation
substitution, do not produce a core constant expression;"

Comment: @DyP: I have asked about [throwing from the ternary operator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20848132/1120273) before with `constexpr`s in mind. However, I didn't expect exceptions to cause compile-time errors when they are thrown and caught: after all, the initialization of the `constexpr` would never be reached...

Comment: I'd just say the initializer is not a constant expression, therefore ill-formed. That's at least how I understand it. Note that [expr.const] contains an example for constexpr functions being resolved to non-constant-expressions.

Comment: Maybe I'm oversimplifying the question, but I found the clang++ error `test.cpp:17:23: error: constexpr variable 'f42' must be initialized by a constant expression` to be rather clear...?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I understand the error message. However, since an exception is thrown while evaluating the initializer of the `constexpr` variable, the code never gets to the initialization. I'm not saying that is wrong that an error is produced rather than exception (I think I even prefer it that way) but I still consider it odd.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The initialiser for a `constexpr` variable must be a constant expression (C++11 §7.1.5/9):

> A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as `const`. Such an object shall have literal type and shall be initialized. If it is initialized by a constructor call, [...]. Otherwise, or if a `constexpr` specifier is used in a reference declaration, every full-expression that appears in its initializer shall be a constant expression.

Note the following requirements for a constant expression (§5.19/2):

> A *conditional-expression* is a *core constant expression* unless it involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated subexpression, but subexpressions of [...] conditional operations that are not evaluated are not considered
>
> - [...]
> - an invocation of a `constexpr` function with arguments that, when substituted by function invocation substitution (7.1.5), do not produce a constant expression;
> - [...]
> - a *throw-expression* (15.1).

Function invocation substitution for a `constexpr` function is defined as follows (§7.1.5/5):

> *Function invocation substitution* for a call of a `constexpr` function [...] means implicitly converting each argument to the corresponding parameter type as if by copy-initialization, substituting that converted expression for each use of the corresponding parameter in the *function-body*, and [...] implicitly converting the resulting returned expression or *braced-init-list* to the return type of the function as if by copy-initialization. Such substitution does not change the meaning.

As we saw above (§5.19/2), subexpressions of conditional operations that are not evaluated are not considered. `f(42)` is not a constant expression because when you perform function invocation substitution on `f`, it results in an expression with a `throw` expression on the side of the conditional operation that is evaluated. On the other hand, for `f(41)`, the `throw` ends up on the side that *isn't* evaluated.

So the program is ill-formed. It doesn't matter whether the initialiser is actually reached or not because the program shouldn't compile.

Comment: 7.1.5/5 is subject to [CWG 1369](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1369) (and possibly other defects).

Comment: @DyP Good to note, but I don't think it affects this explanation.